# hello , so i'm working on my logging for my project using Django and the auth is with metamask but when the user tries to register the data isnt saved

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

when the user logs for the first time using metamask , he's redirected to the register form to complete his account by adding email , first name , last name and password but when the user submit thr form and i check the admin dashboard i only see the username aka the eth address but the other info from the form arent saved , here's the view :

```
import json
import requests
import datetime
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import RegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


API_KEY = 'some key'

def moralis_auth(request):
   return render(request, 'login.html', {})


def request_message(request):
   data = json.loads(request.body)
   print(data)

   REQUEST_URL = 'https://authapi.moralis.io/challenge/request/evm'
   
   # Adjusted expiration time to 5 minutes from the current time
   expiration_time = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)).isoformat() + "Z"

   request_object = {
       "domain": "defi.finance",
       "chainId": 1,
       "address": data['address'],
       "statement": "Please confirm",
       "uri": "https://defi.finance/",
       "expirationTime": expiration_time,
       "notBefore": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
       "timeout": 15
   }
   x = requests.post(
       REQUEST_URL,
       json=request_object,
       headers={'X-API-KEY': API_KEY})

   return JsonResponse(json.loads(x.text))

def verify_message(request):
   data = json.loads(request.body)
   print(data)

   REQUEST_URL = 'https://authapi.moralis.io/challenge/verify/evm'
   x = requests.post(
       REQUEST_URL,
       json=data,
       headers={'X-API-KEY': API_KEY})
   print(json.loads(x.text))
   print(x.status_code)
   if x.status_code == 201:
       # user can authenticate
       eth_address = json.loads(x.text).get('address')
       print("eth address", eth_address)
       try:
           user = User.objects.get(username=eth_address)
       except User.DoesNotExist:
           # If user does not exist, create a new user
           user = User.objects.create_user(username=eth_address, password=None)
           user.save()
           # Set a flag in the session to indicate that the user needs to complete the registration process
           request.session['needs_registration'] = True
       if user is not None:
           if user.is_active:
               login(request, user)
           request.session['auth_info'] = data
           request.session['verified_data'] = json.loads(x.text)
           return JsonResponse({'user': user.username})
       else:
           return JsonResponse({'error': 'account disabled'})
   else:
       # If user does not exist, create a new user
       user = User.objects.create_user(username= eth_address, password=None)
       user.save()
       # Set a flag in the session to indicate that the user needs to complete the registration process
       request.session['needs_registration'] = True
       return JsonResponse(json.loads(x.text))


def register(request):
    # Assuming your verification process sets 'needs_registration' in the session
    needs_registration = request.session.get('needs_registration', False)

    # If the user doesn't need registration, redirect to the profile
    if not needs_registration:
        return redirect('my_profile')

    form = RegisterForm(request=request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST, request=request)
        if form.is_valid():
            eth_address = request.session.get('verified_data', {}).get('address')
            
            # Check if the user already exists
            user_exists = User.objects.filter(username=eth_address).exists()

            if user_exists:
                # User exists, proceed with login
                user = User.objects.get(username=eth_address)
            else:
                # User doesn't exist, create the user
                user = form.save()

            # Authenticate the user
            login(request, user)

            # Set 'needs_registration' to False after registration
            request.session['needs_registration'] = False

            # Redirect to the user's profile
            return redirect('my_profile')

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def my_profile(request):
   eth_address = request.user.username

   if User.objects.filter(username=eth_address).exists():
       print("User already exists in the database")
       if 'needs_registration' in request.session:
           print("User needs registration")
           # Clear the 'needs_registration' flag from the session to prevent infinite redirection loop
           del request.session['needs_registration']
           return redirect('register')
       else:
           print("User does not need registration")
           return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user': request.user})
   else:
       print("User does not exist in the database")
       return redirect('register')
```

this is my form.py :

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "first_name", "last_name", "password"]

    def __init__(self, *args, request=None, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if request:
            self.fields['username'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
            self.fields['username'].initial = request.session.get('verified_data', {}).get('address')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Override the save method to handle user instance updates
        user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)

        # Update user data
        user.email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data.get('password'))

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

and this is the register form :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Register</h1>
   <form method="POST" id="registrationForm">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}
       <button type="submit">Register</button>
       {% if form.errors %}
    <div style="color: red;">
        <strong>Error(s):</strong>
        <ul>
            {% for error in form.errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}
   </form>

   <script>
    document.getElementById('registrationForm').addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Fetch the form data
        const formData = new FormData(this);

        try {
            // Make an asynchronous POST request to the registration endpoint
            const response = await fetch('/web3_auth/register', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
            });

            // Check if the registration was successful
            if (response.ok) {
                // Redirect the user to the dynamically generated profile page URL
                const profileUrl = '{% url 'my_profile' %}';
                window.location.href = profileUrl;
            } else {
                // Handle registration errors (show an alert, update UI, etc.)
                alert('Registration failed. Please try again.');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('An error occurred during registration:', error);
            alert('An error occurred during registration. Please try again.');
        }
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

i dont get any error it just the data doesnt get saved